# How do you convert a python sequence item to an integer

Tags: python, string

I need to convert the elements of a python2.7 bytearray() or string or bytes() into integers for processing.  In many languages(ie C, etc) bytes and 'chars' are more or less 8 bit ints that you an perform math operations on.  How can I convince python to let me use (appropriate) bytearrays or strings interchangebly?

Consider toHex(stringlikeThing):

```
zerof = '0123456789ABCDEF'
def toHex(strg):
    ba = bytearray(len(strg)*2)
    for xx in range(len(strg)):
        vv = ord(strg[xx])
        ba[xx*2] = zerof[vv>>4]
        ba[xx*2+1] = zerof[vv&0xf]
    return ba
```

which should take a string like thing (ie bytearray or string) and make a printable string like thing of hexadecimal text.  It converts "string" to the hex ASCII:

```
>>> toHex("string")
bytearray(b'737472696E67')
```

However, when given a bytearray:

```
>>> nobCom.toHex(bytearray("bytes"))
EX ord() expected string of length 1, but int found: 0 bytes
```

The ord() in the 'for' loop gets strg[xx], an item of a bytearray, which seems to be an integer (Whereas an item of a str is a single element string)
So ord() wants a char (single element string) not an int.

Is there some method or function that takes an argument that is a byte, char, small int, one element string and returns it's value?

---

Of course you could check the type(strg[xx]) and handle the cases laboriously.

The unvoiced question is: Why (what is the reasoning) for Python to be so picky about the difference between a byte and char (normal or unicode) (ie single element string)?

Comment: Strings are byte sequences in Python 2.

Comment: Why is `toHex` returning a byte array? It's not binary data, it's textual data.  Similarly, `toHex` should be operating on binary data, not strings.

Comment: Re your first and last paragraphs: Please read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html). Python 2 did store binary data and text data in the same type (string), which caused subtle bugs because people weren't thinking about encoding.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html

Comment: @Colonel Thirty Two  toHex returns a bytearray so it is mutable.  I guess returning an immutable str is no fine for its intended use.  But that doesn't change the issue of flexible input format (str or bytearray)  I think some things like socket.recv() returns a str doesn't it, the net protocol I'm using has some binary data with characters intermixed.  toHex was to let me see the binary data for development

Comment: The underlying problem is that socket.recv() returns a str -- but the data being sent on most/many TCP sockets is binary data.  Therefore you can't just think of it as unicode characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you index a `bytearray` object in python, you get an integer. This integer is the code for the corresponding character in the bytearray, or in other words, the very thing that the `ord` function would return.

There is no method in python that takes a byte, character, small integer, or one element string and returns it's value in python. Making such a method would be simple however.

```
def toInt(x):
     return x if type(x) == int else ord(x)
```